# Swift 4 array images show with food loop

Tags: arrays, swift, image, loops

This is my code in swift 4 xcode. i have problems with my code. I can't show my array, with images on the simulator what things I'm doing wrong?
im a beginner in swift. and i have tried too look up how you write an array with images with four loop but the simulator docent show

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let img : UIImage = UIImage(named: "owl")!
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: img )
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)

      //  var images = Array<UIImage>()
        //images.append(UIImage(named: "lion")!,

                      let ImgArray = ["lion.png","wolf.png","snake.png"]
        var images = [UIImage]()

        for i in 0..<ImgArray.count
        {
            images.append(UIImage(named: ImgArray[i])!)
        }
        let imageView2 = UIImageView(image: img )
        self.view.addSubview(imageView2)
    }

}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but, you’re breaking idea of foreach loop. You can simply say for each element in array do this, not just for its index. So you can say `for imgName in ImgArray { ... }` and then you can use this name for initializing an image `UIImage(named: imgName)`

Comment: thank you! i dont understand so much but i tried to do what you said i think

Use of unresolved identifier 'ImgArray' i get this wrong massge now, i added a class to.

let Array = ["lion.png","wolf.png"]

    var images = [UIImage]()

    for imgName in ImgArray
    {
        images.append(UIImage(named: images))


    }
} class images { var images: UIImage init(images: UIImage) { self.images = images } } }

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @Robert, instead of using the index of the array, you can use a `for loop` this way :

```
let imagesNames = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png"]

for imageName in imagesNames {
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    images.append(image)
}
```

You can also use `map` to directly transform your `array` of images names to an `array` of images :

```
let imagesNames = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png"]
let images = imagesNames.map { UIImage(named: $0) }
```

where `0$` is your `imageName`.

Comment: Please, use `map`.

Comment: He is a beginner, this usage of `for loop` is easier to understand, but I add the `map` method to my answer !